# Nginx as reverse proxy on Ubuntu for Asp.Net Core 2.0 web app with UseRewriter

Tags: c#, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, asp.net-core

As explained in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl), I setup my Startup class as follows:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Environment = environment;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var secretsFolder = Path.Combine(Configuration["SecretsFolder"].Split('/'));
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(secretsFolder, "keys")));

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration["MyAppDbConnectionString"] +
                "User ID=" + Configuration["DatabaseUser"] +
                ";Password=" + Configuration["DatabasePassword"] + ";";
            options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.Name = ".MyApp.Identity";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
        });

        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".MyApp.AntiCSRF";
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());

            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());

            // Make authentication compulsory by default; 
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl
        var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
        app.UseRewriter(options);

        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

On Ubuntu 16.04, I installed Nginx from default ubuntu repo, then installed LetsEncrypt. Below is the content of /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;
    root /home/me/myapp/wwwroot;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Note that I haven't changed /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (which has include directive referring to /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file).

But when a https://myapp.com request is made, my app throws the following error:

> The antiforgery system has the configuration value AntiforgeryOptions.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Always, but the current request is not an SSL request.

Google Chrome shows:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

If I comment out the following code:

```
        //var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
        //app.UseRewriter(options);
```

the error disappears, and my app works as expected.

Please, explain the issue. How can I configure nginx so that my web app still works without commenting out the above code? Or should I get rid of programmatic redirect, if nginx already configured to redirect http to https?

Answer (score 2):

> Google Chrome shows:
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

As you can see from your nginx configuration, it forwards user requests to your back end server over an http protocol, not https. That is a common practice as you may know, your back end servers must be in the private network (an example of how it may work https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing-with-ssl-termination).

> proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;

But your back end server would always return 302 redirect, since

```
options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());

// this filter redirects to https
```

and

```
var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
app.UseRewriter(options);

// this rewrite redirects to https
```

So, you have two places where your back end server would return 302 redirect.

That way, when you open https://myapp.com, nginx forwards your request to your back end server over http protocol, it responds with a 302 redirect to https protocol (https://myapp.com), and the cycle repeats.

### To fix this and other related to this issue problems make sure

1) Nginx sends `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers to the back end server after it received a user request over https.

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

✓ your nginx configuration has that

2) Asp Core uses these headers

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

✓ your app uses the headers

3) the `RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps()` part goes after the `app.UseForwardedHeaders` part

❌ that's why **your** application is stuck in redirect loop

---

And since mvc filters are applied after middleware, `options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute())` doesn't complain about https if your rewrite redirect is commented out.

But if you remove both `app.UseForwardedHeaders` and your rewrite redirect, you would get another redirect loop, but now it is caused by the mvc filter.

And, if you remove the filter, The antiforgery system would start complain about cookies by throwing `The antiforgery system has the configuration value AntiforgeryOptions.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Always, but the current request is not an SSL request.` exception.